# Move emails older then x years to different mailbox in Outlook / Office365

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have a 50GB mailbox at Office365 which is almost full, and just created a second one to be used as archive. I want to archive all emails older then x years to the second mailbox and keep the folder structure.

The online archive is not an option, as I need all email to be available offline as well.

I have access to both Outlook 2016 for Mac and Windows.

The only way I can think of is setting up archiveing to a PST in the Windows based Outlook version and import that PST to the second mailbox

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the Exchange PowerShell to move old emails to PST file and then import the PST to a new mailbox ([New-MailboxExportRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607299(v=exchg.160).aspx) and [New-MailboxImportRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607310(v=exchg.160).aspx) cmdlets). This is only if you have the access to remote powershell session.
2. You can use the [Merge Outlook Stores](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookStorageMerge) to move all emails at once. Just click the Configure button, select the source mailbox, then specify the new mailbox as a destination, set "Move source items..." option and specify required date range. I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers.